# Query DynamoDb for multiple items

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I think I'm misunderstanding DynamoDb. I would like to query for all items, with a child field of the json, which match an identifier I'm passing. The structure is something like -

```
{
        "messageId": "ced96cab-767e-509198be5-3d2896a3efeb",
        "identifier": {
            "primary": "9927fd47-5d33-4f51-a5bb-f292a0c733b1",
            "secondary": "none",
            "tertiary": "cfd96cab-767e-5091-8be5-3d2896a3efeb"
        },
        "attributes": {
            "MyID": {
                "Type": "String",
                "Value": "9927fd47-5c33-4f51-a5bb-f292a0c733b1"
            }
        }
}
```

I would like to query for all items in DynamoDb that has a value of MyID that I'm passing. Everything I've read seems to say you need to use the key which in my case is the messageId, this is unique for each entry and not a value I can use.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: You need to do a `scan` instead of a `query`. Or perhaps add a global secondary index on `MyID.Value` and then run your query against that index.

Answer (score 0):

The **DynamoDB Query API** can be used only if you know the value of **Partition key**. Otherwise, you may need to scan the whole table using `FilterExpression` to find the item.

[Scanning tables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html)

You can create GSI on scalar attribute only. In the above case, it is a document data type (i.e. MAP). So, GSI can't be created.

Comment: So DyanamoDB can't be used like a traditional database? I still think I'm missing something about the partition key. Surely the key needs to be unique so how would I store multiple items with the same key?